# Merge tags windows-integrated-auth*

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please merge the tags [windows-integrated-authe](/questions/tagged/windows-integrated-authe) and [windows-integrated-authen](/questions/tagged/windows-integrated-authen) on Stack Overflow.

Better name: [windows-integrated-auth](/questions/tagged/windows-integrated-auth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are together about 50 questions it is much simpler to change the tags by hand. I'll stated that.

So far I'm finished with that. But there are about 5 left which I cannot edit without removing my filters.

Comment: Changing 50 questions is simpler? Wow. Sounds like a lot of wasted time to me.

Comment: I took about 8 minutes. So far I see no problem with that.